# Javascript group by with an array of objects to obtain a final keys

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and am looking for the most efficient way with es6 to group them based on the material_id

```
var data=[
  {material_id:1, item:'test'},
  {material_id:1,  item:'test2'},
  {material_id:2,  item:'test2'},
]
```

So at the end i want to get

```
var final_data = [
  1,2
 ]
```

THat is the id's from the grouped material_id

SO i have tried this but am stuck on how to proceed further

```
let final_data = [];
data.forEach(item=>{
      //stuck here
})
```

I have checked on [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)  but it doesnt seem to show a grouping

Comment: Why don't you use `groupBy` method of `lodash`? https://lodash.com/docs/#groupBy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `map()` to get an array of all ids and then use `Set` to remove duplicates

```js
var data=[
  {material_id:1, item:'test'},
  {material_id:1,  item:'test2'},
  {material_id:2,  item:'test2'},
]
let res = [...new Set(data.map(x => x.material_id))]
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

With a [unique](https://appdividend.com/2019/04/11/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-array-in-javascript/) function, I was able to solve the problem like so:

```
const unique = (value, index, self) => {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index
}


const data =[
  {material_id:1, item:'test'},
  {material_id:1,  item:'test2'},
  {material_id:2,  item:'test2'},
];

var final_data = [];

for(var i in data) {
    let row = data[i];
    final_data.push(row.material_id);
}
final_data = final_data.filter(unique);

console.log(final_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to group your array and use `Object.keys` to get key of result.

```js
var data=[
  {material_id:1, item:'test'},
  {material_id:1,  item:'test2'},
  {material_id:2,  item:'test2'},
]

let result = data.reduce((r, a) => {

  const {
    material_id,
    item
  } = a;

  r[a.material_id] = [...r[a.material_id] || [], {
    material_id,
    item
  }];

  return r;
}, {});


console.log(Object.keys(result));
```